# Comparison of arrays (element by element)

Tags: c, algorithm, compare, comparison, vectorization

An algorithm that I am working with spends a huge portion of the time comparing one array with a row of a matrix. If any *ith* element is the same, the algorithm calls a procedure A, if no elements are equal, procedure B is invoked instead. For example:

`[1, 4, 10, 3, 5]` and `[5, 3, 0, 3, 0]` calls `A()` because for the 4th position, the value is 3 in both arrays.

`[1, 4, 10, 3, 5]` and `[5, 3, 0, 1, 0]` calls `B()` because for the same position, the values are never the same.

Note that (1) the arrays and matrix rows have always the same size N, and (2) the algorithm calls `A()` **when at least one** value matches.

The simplest but very naïve way of doing this in C is with:

```
for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
   if( A[i] == B[i] ){
      flag = 1;
      break;
   }
```

This is still very inefficient. On the worst case, I'll have N comparisons. The real problem here is that the algorithm does trillions of these comparisons.

N (the size of the array/row in the matrix) varies from 100 to 1000. I'd like to speedup this routine. I looked at vectorization and I found that I can use `cmpeq_pd`. However, vectorization will still be limited because **all my entries are** **`longs`**. Is there anybody with an idea? Can I apply masks and such, maybe?

More information/context:

- This is an iterative algorithm. At every iteration, I increment the matrix in one row and check the whole matrix several times. I might update a couple rows as well.
- The likelihood for a match does not depend on the position.
- I am willing to have false positives and negatives, in order to speedup this routine considerably.
- If there is a match, the position in which a match is verified is **not** relevant (I just need to know if there is a matching position).
- The biggest number (about 70%) of comparisons does not result in a match.
- Parallelization is done at a different level, i.e. this kernel cannot be parallelized.

Comment: Can you keep track of differences? So that for all rows you keep a tally of equal elements, which you update when you update the matrix cells or array elements. (That will work only for some cases, of course.)

Comment: The idea is to keep auxiliary data alongside your matrix that you can easily update when you change the matrix. Let's say you keep the number of equal elements of an array and a row `i`. When you update a cell in the matrix, check against the row, and decrement this value if it matches. Calculate the new value, then check again and adjust the number of matching items again. Your test for row `i` will become `match[i] == 0`. Whether this is possible depends on what you want to do exactly.

Comment: You can of course try the usual micro-optimizations (loop unrolling and making sure everything is `const` spring to mind), if you've profiled and/or read the generated code so that you know that the compiler shares your naïvite.

Comment: You need to give more information about the content of the matrix and the arrays.   How often are they updated? [relevant to being able to look up results rather than recalculating].  Is there a greater likelihood of a match at the beginning or end of an array?   Are you willing to accept false hits or misses (e.g. calling A when B should be called, or vice versa).   Any optimisation approach will rely on being able to take some shortcuts, and you've given no basis on which some shortcuts might be permitted.

Comment: Is the actual position of the matching element important, i.e. is it passed to `A()` when the match is found? And do you mean that `A()` or `B()` is called when a match is found? You claim both ...

Comment: @Peter This is an iterative algorithm. At every iteration, I increment the matrix in one row and check the whole matrix several times. I might update a couple rows as well. The likelihood you mention is exactly the same for any position of the vector, acc. to the properties of the algorithm. I am willing to relax this, yes. Shortcuts are thus permitted here.

Comment: Your question is now contradictory. First decide what you want to ask. 1. *`[1, 4, 10, 3, 5]` and `[5, 3, 0, 1, 0]` calls `B()` **because for the same position, the values are never the same**.* 2. *The **position** in which a match is verified **is not relevant***

Comment: @haccks Please read the info once again. There is no contraction: If there is a match, the position in which the match occurred is not relevant.

Comment: @a3mlord There is a contradiction regarding which function to call when a match is found, as I pointed out above, 20 minutes ago.

Comment: @unwind; Agreed. I was just thinking about the same. Thanks, BTW

Comment: @unwind That was a typo. When there is a match, the algorithm calls `A()`. I think I wrote `B` because the matching instance was below. It is corrected now.

Comment: Maybe you can save some bytes with a solution like this: `while (( A[i]-B[i] != 0) && (i<N)) i++;`

Comment: @LPs Why would that save bytes? Sorry, I don't get it.

Comment: I'm hardly an algorithm guru, but if the data isn't sorted, I don't really see how you could speed this up further, apart from optimizations not related to the algorithm itself.

Comment: I'm thinking that any significant manual optimization of the original code will revolve around things like cache memory optimization and memory alignment etc... all such things quite system-specific.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77007/discussion-on-question-by-a3mlord-comparison-of-arrays-element-by-element).

Comment: How come you do trillions of these comparisons? Do you execute this kernel a lot for the same array or do you keep multiple instances of these arrays?

Comment: PCMPEQD instruction is for integer comparison

Comment: Can we assume a fairly recent CPU, e.g. Haswell, such that AVX/AVX2 is available ? That would allow for 4 way SIMD, even if your data elements are 64 bit.

Comment: That loop shouts for `#pragma omp parallel for`, if you ask me

Comment: @Beko Parallelization is done at a different level.

Comment: @PaulR Sadly, I am working with Sandy Bridge, and so I can only pack two elements per SSE register.

Comment: OK, well unless you can reduce your 64 bit data to 32 bit somehow, and thereby get 4 way SIMD, then I think you're out of luck.

Comment: @PaulR What I thought was to pack segments of the elements (say the first 16 bits) into 128-wide registers and compare those. As the vast majority of the comparisons test negative, I think that comparing a small part of the bits will immediately exclude a lot of comparisons. When the first say 16 bits match, I move onto the next chunk till all the chunks are compared or one fails. The real challenge is how to do this.

Comment: I'm not totally sure this will help, since you won't reduce memory bandwidth or cache footprint, and the extra instructions for the packing will probably cancel out any benefit from the potentially 2x faster testing. I do have one other idea, which I'll put in an answer shortly.

Comment: @PaulR The idea would be that I could make 8 comparisons instead of 2. Since this algorithm is compute bound, I think this would help. I totally agree that I  won't reduce memory bandwidth and cache footprint, though.

Comment: You didn't say how many rows there are. If you represent the matrix as a set of columns: C[i], then for each element of the array at position i, you can lookup C[i] which tells you which rows match. This could reduce your compares. The set could be a hashtable keyed on the long, with a list of row numbers that match.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know whether this is applicable for the app you are developing, but operations on huge arrays are usually very well accelerated on GPU. You can expect 10-20x throughput speedup over CPU. If it's possible for your app to run the critical portion on [CUDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA) that would make a huge difference.

Comment: @a3mlord try earlier if possible - use the OpenCL SDK for your CPU and do a comparison of elements + parallel prefix sum and send that back to the host code.  This should multicore decently but ultimately you are severely limited in memory bandwidth it sounds.  The only possible savings I could think of it that's the case is if your data is quasistatic or static in which case doing the comparison/sum GPU will give you billions / second memory bandwidth there is 20x faster than the beefiest intel PCs - but the PCIe bandwidth is a factor or 4 less than PC memory bandwidth.

Answer (score 2):

Although your Sandy Bridge CPU only has AVX for 256 bit SIMD (and not AVX2), and therefore lacks supports for 4 way SIMD 64 bit integer operations, I think you can still achieve 4 way SIMD using AVX floating point instructions, as follows: to compare 2 x 256 bit vectors of 64 bit integer values, `v1`, `v2`:

```
__m256d vcmp = _mm256_xor_pd(v1, v2); // use XOR rather than compare, so we are not 
                                      // affected by values which map to NaNs
vcmp = _mm256_cmp_pd(vcmp, _mm256_setzero_pd(), _CMP_EQ_OQ);
                                      // now we can do a valid comparison as if the
                                      // data really is double precision float
int mask = _mm256_movemask_pd(vcmp);  // extract the sign bits
bool any_eq = (mask != 0);            // if any elements matched then mask
                                      // will be non-zero
```

Here is an example program for test and illustration purposes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

int test(__m256d v1, __m256d v2)
{
    __m256d vcmp = _mm256_xor_pd(v1, v2);
    vcmp = _mm256_cmp_pd(vcmp, _mm256_setzero_pd(), _CMP_EQ_OQ);
    return _mm256_movemask_pd(vcmp);
}

int main()
{
    int64_t a1[4] = { 3098, 3860, 405, 3308 };
    int64_t a2[4] = { 1930, 1274, 2195, 2939 };
    int64_t a3[4] = { 1930, 1274, 405, 2939 };

    __m256i v1 = _mm256_loadu_pd((double *)a1);
    __m256i v2 = _mm256_loadu_pd((double *)a2);
    __m256i v3 = _mm256_loadu_pd((double *)a3);

    printf("mask = %d (should be == 0)\n", test(v1, v2));

    printf("mask = %d (should be != 0)\n", test(v1, v3));

    return 0;
}
```

Test:

```
$ gcc -Wall -mavx a3mlord2.c && ./a.out 
mask = 0 (should be == 0)
mask = 4 (should be != 0)
```

Comment: Paul, could you please post the load instruction? I used ``__m256d v1 = _mm256_loadu_ps((float *)&array[index] );``, but I think this is wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Since this is 64 bit data you would probably want `_mm256_loadu_pd`.

Comment: Thanks Paul, perfect. I am now using ``__m256d v1 = _mm256_loadu_pd((const double *)&array[index] );``. However, this gives me a different output at the end. I will try to figure out whats wrong.

Comment: The result is different, because this is generating wrong comparisons:

``v1 3098 3860 405 3308 
v2 1930 1274 2195 2939 
MATCH``

Comment: I just tried it here with your example and it seems to work fine - there may be a problem in the way you are calling the code. I'll add my test code to the answer shortly...

Comment: Compiler issues... I am using ``icc``. With ``gcc`` it works fine. Do you know what to get it to work with ``icc``?

Comment: Maybe try disabling strict aliasing ?

Comment: Paul, doesn't work (and I also tried a bunch of other things). Sadly, I am bounded to icc/icpc at this point, which means that I can't assess the goodness of this. My mask is always 15.

Comment: What version of ICC are you using ?

Comment: icc version 13.1.3 (gcc version 4.7.0 compatibility)

Comment: I just tried ICC 13 here and I see the same problem - I'll take a look and see if I can find a workaround...

Comment: No luck - it seems to be a bug with `_mm256_cmp_pd` in ICC 13. If I can get access to a newer version of ICC I'll try with that, but for now I don't see any way to work around this.

Comment: Thanks for the effort Paul, I do appreciate it!

Comment: No problem - ICC 13 seems to have an awful lot of bugs - you might want to try getting the 30 day evaluation of ICC 15 (or whatever the current version is) and try that and maybe consider upgrading if it works out.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you look for optimisations, there are different paths in front of you:

- algorithmic optimization: typically a sort algorithm to use, in your case using some dependencies in or between rows to only test some cases on not the N values. You did not say anything we can use for that, but maybe **you** know such rules - this kind of optimization can have gains by order of magnitude
- medium level optimization: once you have chosen your algorithm, check how you organize your loops and tests - here again, I have no idea of what can be done - gain usually around 10% except in terrible implementations
- low level optimizations: trying to be cleverer than an optimizing compiler generally make you loose, but in some cases benchmarking different implementation may give an gain of some per cent
- parallelization: if the algorithm supports it, you divide the total processing on a number or cores or processors. The expected gain is generally a little below the number of simultaneous threads.

With what you said, the only possible optimization would be to parallelize the processing on n cores, each core (minus one) doing a part of the row, and another one processing the result of those first comparisons. But as said before, if there are rules in data, gain can be much higher.

Answer (score 1):

*The simplest but very naïve way of doing this in C is with*
As you are implying by your questions, the code example you provide under this statement may be simple from a readability viewpoint, but does it translate to the simplest most efficient method for comparison of data once compiled?

Suggest trying a block compare:
The way data is presented for comparison can contribute to *speed and efficiency* of comparison.  Load the values into separate variables, (assigned to use separate registers), then compare the registers.

```
long a1 = A[0];
long a2 = A[1];
long a3 = A[2];
long a4 = A[3];
...
long an = A[n];

long b1 = B[0];
long b2 = B[1];
long b3 = B[2];
long b4 = B[3];
...
long bn = B[n];

if ((a1 == b1) || (a2 == b2) || (a3 == b3) || (a4 == b4) ... || (an == bn))
{
   //do something
}
else
{
   //do something else
}
```

To really know if a method is the fastest, code it, look at the assembly it generates, or benchmark test it.  As you suggested in your post, looping on the array elements is probably not the most efficient way.

***EDIT***:  an oblique idea:  Matlab is known for including some of the fastest array comparison routines, *And* it also has a Matlab to C conversion capability.  If you, or a colleague has a copy of Matlab, you might try some speed testing for algorithms created using Matlab, then convert to C to observe what it creates.  I have used this feature before, the C constructs it has produced are not pretty to look at, but typically very efficient (in terms of speed).

Comment: Considering that I will have hundreds or thousands of elements, won't I re-write the registers in the assignments, just prior to comparison?

Comment: Yes. each time this segment is called.   And I would imagine  the above example to be much longer,  but although ugly, a long line of sequential assignment statements, then a block comparison will be more efficient than looping through a series of array element comparisons.  For readability (but reduced de-bugability) you could define macros in a header file.  But again, from a C coding perspective, I think this approach will add some level of efficiency over looping comparisons.  Very well laid out question by the way.

Answer (score 0):

SIMD processing is not likely to help at all: You have a fairly small loop which touches a lot of data (16 bytes per iteration). This will likely saturate the memory bus even when run without SIMD.

As I see it, you have two basic options:

1. You use more/wider memory buses.
   That can be achieved by using multiple cores or GPUs.
2. You try to reduce the number of comparisons.
   Whether that is possible is unclear from your question, but if your algorithm does the same comparison several times, you can restructure your algorithm by caching the comparison results. Depending on the algorithm, that can give significant speedups.

Answer (score -3):

If you're using gcc and if you are on an x86 platform, your code could likely benefit from using `memcmp()` instead of an "homegrown" `for` loop. `memcmp()` (respectively it's builtin counterpart) does some pretty smart optimizations.

Comment: OP is looking to see if **any** of the elements in the array are equal.  This will tell us if **all** of the elements are equal.

Comment: As far as I know, speaking on longs arrays, the optimization of memcmp is nothing..